# Reset Zoomed Image When Switching to next Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android, zooming, imagelibrary

I am working on a magazine type application for galaxy tab 10.1. I have created each page using Fragment.User can swipe his finger horizontally to move to next page which is a different fragment. Most of the pages are "full page image".I am using [this](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/) library for zooming/pinch zoom static pages/images.
Problem I am facing -

(1)  If i zoom-in a page and than scroll to left or right end of page and than move to next fragment/page.After that when i go back to previous fragment/page,the page is still in zoomed state. What i am trying to do is reset the page in normal state when i move to next page/fragment.

Thanks